# SQL statement - double and single quote confusion

Tags: php, sql

I've stared and stared at this but cannot seem to understand why it is not working.  Something is up with my use of single quotes and double quotes, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

My error:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

**the query** 
note: yes the cookies I am looking for is set.

```
$var_results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `variable` WHERE experimentid='" . $exp_row['experimentid'] . "' AND variabletype='" . $_COOKIE['vartype'] . "'");
```

**the while loop that uses query results - the while loop is what is shooting me the error.**

```
while ($var_row = mysqli_fetch_array($var_results, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The fact that the parameter is not a mysqli_result just indicates that the query failed for some reason. The rest is just basic debugging. Use `mysqli_error` to find the error that occured - or echo out the query string to make sure it ends up looking like you're expecting, and then try running the echo'd query manually.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's got anything to do with the quotes. I think it's more likely that either `$exp_row['experimentid']` or `$_COOKIE['vartype']` does not contain what you're expecting.

Comment: did you try echoing the resulting query as a string?

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering when to use single quotes and when not to, you want to use single quotes on data types such as varchar, char, etc, and do not use single quotes on numeric types such as int, decimal, etc. If your experimentid is a numeric type, then you might want to remove the single quotes. Also, I'm relatively sure you don't need the back ticks on your table name.